# Estimator for the conditional expectation operator with convergence rate in operator norm

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, st.statistics, kernels

Let $X$ and $Z$ be two random variables defined on the same probability space, taking values in euclidian spaces $E_X$ and $E_Z$, with distributions $\pi$ and $\nu$, respectively.
Let $L^2(\pi)$ denote the space $L^2(E_X, \mathcal{B}(E_X), \pi ; \mathbb{R})$ of real (equivalence classes of) functions $f : E_X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
\mathbb{E} [f(X)^2] < \infty.
$$
Define the space $L^2(\nu)$ accordingly.
I'm interested in estimating the bounded linear operator $P : L^2(\pi) \to L^2(\nu)$ given by
$$
Pf(z) = \mathbb{E} [f(X) \mid Z = z],
$$
that is, the conditional expectation operator.
The data I'm allowed to use is independent samples of the pair $(X, Z)$.
I'm looking for an estimator $\hat{P}$ with some sort of convergence rate in the operator norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{L^2(\pi) \to L^2(\nu)}$.
The convergence rate does not need to be in mean, an $\mathcal{O}_p$-like bound would be enough.

I'm aware of kernel based methods which simplify the problem by substituting $L^2(\pi)$ and $L^2(\nu)$ by dense RKHS subspaces $\mathcal{H}_X$ and $\mathcal{H}_Z$, and then estimate $P : \mathcal{H}_X \to \mathcal{H}_Z$ using Hilbert-Schmidt operators as a hypothesis class. However, the convergence rates are expressed in terms of the HS norm between the spaces $\mathcal{H}_X$ and $\mathcal{H}_Z$, and I really need it to be between $L^2(\pi)$ and $L^2(\nu)$. I'm looking for any references that achieves this.

I decided to post this here because although the question's subject is an inherently statistical concept (the "regression function" or conditional expectation), I felt that the mathematical community here would be of greater help than the folks at Cross Validated.